# How can I insert separately a photo and text using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sms

How can I separate posting or inserting a photo or text not together to my database which is mysql database.

In this line of code I can post both a picture and a text together, but if I want only a picture it shows the error in the code.

```
<?php
include('includes/database.php');
include('session.php');

if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo "";
}else{
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image = $_FILES["image"] ["name"];
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $size = $_FILES["image"] ["size"];
    $error = $_FILES["image"] ["error"];

    if ($error > 0){
        die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
    }else{
        if($size > 10000000){ //conditions for the file
            die("Format is not allowed or file size is too big!");
        }else{

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);          
            $location="upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
            $user=$_SESSION['id'];
            $content=$_POST['content'];
            $time=time();

            $update=mysql_query(" INSERT INTO post (user_id,post_image,content,created)
            VALUES ('$id','$location','$content','$time') ") or die (mySQL_error());

        }
    header('location:home.php');
    }
}
?>
```

This is the form that corresponds the code above.

```
<div id="right-nav">
    <h1>Update Status</h1>
    <form method="post" action="post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea placeholder="Whats on your mind?" name="content" class="post-text" required></textarea>
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <button class="btn-share" name="Submit" value="Log out">Share</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you for future answers.

Comment: So the code above is working good, but you don't want to save the `$content` in database ?

Comment: I want to save it, but I would like to save or post like facebook. either it is a TEXT or a PHOTO. In my code. it only post if there is a TEXT and a PHOTO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save an image OR a text OR both:

```
<?php
include('includes/database.php');
include('session.php');

$user=$_SESSION['id'];
$time=time();

// Content
if( isset($_POST['content']) && !empty($_POST['content']) ){
    $content=$_POST['content'];
}else{
    $content="";
}

// Image
if ( isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) ) {
    $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $image = $_FILES["image"] ["name"];
    $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $size = $_FILES["image"] ["size"];
    $error = $_FILES["image"] ["error"];

    if ($error > 0){
        die("Error uploading file! Code $error.");
    }
    if($size > 10000000){ //conditions for the file
        die("Format is not allowed or file size is too big!");
    }

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);          
    $location="upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
}else{
    $location="";
}

// Save to database if there is content OR an image
// Will save both if both are present

if( !empty($content) || !empty($location) ){
    $update=mysql_query(" INSERT INTO post (user_id,post_image,content,created)
    VALUES ('$id','$location','$content','$time') ") or die (mySQL_error());

    // Redirect to home
    header('location:home.php');
}
?>
```

In all cases, the variables needed for the SQL query are setted.
So there should be no error.

If there is no text AND no image, the script simply does nothing.

Comment: sir btw, can you hide the border of the `<img src="">` ? because even I don't upload picture there is a border -_-

Comment: That is, I suppose, when you display what's in database... A `<img src="">` still has a border because it is defined in CSS. There is several possible approches... [Check here](http://pastebin.com/vugzv0B1).